# kafka in logstash config and sending the output to ES

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok

I am trying to take the data from Kafka and push it to ES index.

```
input {
kafka {
bootstrap_servers => "XX.XXX.XXX.XXX:9092"
topics => ["timeseries_ht"]
}
}
output {
elasticsearch { hosts => ["XX.XXX.XXX.XXX:9200"]
index => "sound"
}
}
```

After running this, index is not created in my ES host . . Is there anything wrong with the configuration? I am using LOGSTASH 5.0.0. and ES 5.0.0 as well.

In Logstash 2.x version :

```
input {
kafka {
zk_connect => "XX.XXX.XXX.XXX:2181"
topic_id => ["timeseries_ht"]
}
}
output {
elasticsearch {
hosts => ["XX.XXX.XXX.XXX:9200"]
index => "sound"
}
}
```

Doesnt work with Logstash 2.x as well. I am not able to see the index creation in my host machine.

Can anyone help where I am doing wrong here ?

Comment: Is data flowing into your topic or is your topic fully loaded and you expect Logstash to consume it from the beginning offset? There used to be a way in Logstash 2.x, but not anymore in 5.x. Maybe try to add `auto_offset_reset => "earliest"`.

Comment: my topic if fully loaded with data and I expect Logstash to consume it. Will try adding it.

Comment: not working out. is there any other way?

Comment: Is there any other way I can consume the kafka data using logstash 5.x

Comment: @Val - I tried with Logstash 2.x version as well., it doesnt seem to work with logstash 2.x version too. Edited my question with the configuration for logstash 2.x.

Comment: With Logstash 2, you could use `auto_offset_reset => "smallest"` + `reset_beginning => true` and it would work

Comment: It worked. you saved my day. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Logstash 2 you can configure your `kafka` input like this and that will work:

```
input {
  kafka {
    zk_connect => "XX.XXX.XXX.XXX:2181"
    topic_id => ["timeseries_ht"]
    auto_offset_reset => "smallest"
    reset_beginning => true
  }
}
output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["XX.XXX.XXX.XXX:9200"]
    index => "sound"
  }
}
```